# In iOS 6, how can I convince Siri that New York City is not in Texas?

Tags: ios, siri

This is NOT a rant about maps or its data.

I live in New York City, and when I ask Siri for the weather, the results seemed a bit... optimistic.  I think it unlikely, for example, that it will be 84 degrees here in NYC on this brisk October afternoon.

After getting the same (much too warm) results when asking for the generic "weather here" as well as "the weather in New York City, New York," I clicked through the Yahoo button to their webapp, which confirmed that while Siri "knows" I'm physically in New York City, NY, that somehow results in a query to yahoo for New York, TX.

If I go straight to the Apple Weather app, it works fine:  both the current location and a directly-typed entry for New York, NY report the correct high of 57 degrees.

So the problem appears to be somewhere between Siri's text parsing (which is working) and Yahoo.

I've tried this on two friends' devices with the same results.

Has anyone found a fix?

Comment: Sounds like quite a bug to me. Never heard the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a legitimate bug with Siri: http://www.macrumors.com/2012/09/24/siri-delivering-wrong-weather-forecasts-for-common-city-names/

The bug has to be fixed on Apple's end (or Yahoo's, or wherever exactly the problem is occurring).

**But you can work around it temporarily by asking for the weather in "Zip Code 10028"** (or whatever).  Note that you seem to have to say "Zip Code" - just using the number doesn't seem to work.

That's a bit surprising that you're seeing it now since it first popped up almost three weeks ago – you'd think they would have fixed it by now. I guess all you can do is wait and it'll resolve itself at some point.